# mutiple inheritance: use __init__ method of two superclasses

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, init, super

I want to make multiple inheritance, making a subclass inherit from two different super classes. This subclass should have an `__init__` method in which the `__init__` methods of the super classes are called with the expected arguments.

Here is an example that can illustrate my problem:

```py
class Place:
   def __init__(self, country, city, **attr):
      self.country = country
      self.city = city
      self.attributes = attr
   
   def show_location(self):
      print(self.country, self.city)

class Product:
   def __init__(self, price, currency = '$'):
      self.price = price
      self.currency = currency

   def show_price(self):
      print(self.price, self.currency)

class Flat(Place, Product):
   def __init__(self, country, city, street, number, price, currency = '$', **attr):
      super(Place).__init__(country, city, **attr)
      super(Product).__init__(price, currency)
      self.street = street
      self.number = number

   def show_address(self):
      print(self.number, self.street)
      
myflat = Flat('Mozambique', 'Nampula', 'Rua dos Combatentes', 4, 150000, '$')
```

But I don't really know how to use the `super()` method, and this code throws the following error:

`TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not str`

I wonder how can I initialize the `Flat` object both as a `Place` and as a `Product`...

Is it appropriate to use `super()` in this context?

Or is it better to call `__init__` directly this way: `SuperClass.__init__(self, ...)` ?

Comment: Inheritance may not even be appropriate here. It seems more like a flat *has*  a place as an attribute, rather than being a special kind of place.

Comment: your use of `super` is totally wrong here

Comment: I would use`Place.__init__(self, ...)` and `Product.__init__(self, ...)`. It repeats the superclas name, but it makes clear which `__init__()` method your are calling at each point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR The article [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) explains in detail how to use `super` correctly.

---

`super` is intended to implement *cooperative* multiple inheritance, where the classes involved are designed together to support such inheritance. This requires redesigning both `Place` and `Product` slightly; the linked article discusses the rationale for the redesign shown below. (If you can't redesign them, the linked article also explains how to define adaptor classes to wrap them.)

```
class Place:
   def __init__(self, *, country, city, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.country = country
      self.city = city
   
   def show_location(self):
      print(self.country, self.city)

class Product:
   def __init__(self, *, price, currency='$', **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.price = price
      self.currency = currency

   def show_price(self):
      print(self.price, self.currency)

class Flat(Place, Product):
   def __init__(self, *, street, number, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.street = street
      self.number = number

   def show_address(self):
      print(self.number, self.street)
      
myflat = Flat(country='Mozambique', city='Nampula', street='Rua dos Combatentes', number=4, price=150000)
```

The key is that `super` refers to the next class in the method resolution order (MRO), a list of classes constructed from the inheritance tree. Only *one* call to `super` is required in each method. Both `Place` and `Product` use it as well, because neither class knows if it will be the last class in the MRO of the object being initialized. (More precisely, both know they *won't*, because `object` itself is always the final class.)

Each `__init__` method accepts a certain number of keyword-only arguments that it knows what to do with, along with arbitrary keyword arguments that it will pass on to one of the ancestor class to handle. Ultimately, if the classes are defined correctly, one of the calls to `super().__init__(**kwargs)` will invoke `object.__init__` with *no* keyword arguments, ending the chain.

Comment: It took me a little while to figure it out, but I understood better when I read the article you referenced. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I answer questions like this far too frequently, but I think most people asking it benefit from seeing their particular example correctly adapted. Rather than making every answer a specialized summary of the article, I just show the end result and link to the article to explain where the result came from. Not ideal, but I don't think there's a single SO duplicate that can encompass all such questions satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly call the two superclass `__init__` like this:

```
class Flat(Place, Product):
    def __init__(self, country, city, street, number, price, currency = '$', **attr):
      Place.__init__(self, country, city, **attr)
      Product.__init__(self, price, currency)
      self.street = street
      self.number = number
```

Comment: The first solution throws a TypeError.

Comment: `super` has not required two arguments since Python 2.7. In virtually every situation, the correct arguments can be inferred and do not need to be provided explicitly.

Comment: @chepner this is exactly one of the situations where both arguments are needed.

Comment: @OskarHofmann what is the full error?

Comment: No, it's not, because you aren't supposed to be calling `super` twice in the first place. The entire class hierarchy is incorrectly defined.

Comment: I take your point that multiple inheritance used in this way is not ideal. But explicitly calling two superclass __init__ methods is valid Python.

Comment: @Dave `TypeError: Product.__init__() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

Comment: @OskarHofmann whoops, that will teach my to answer questions on mobile. Edited to removed the broken example that could never work.

Comment: @Dave no it isn't one of those situations, it a situation where you either need to redesign your class hierarchy to support cooperative multiple inheritance, or *simply not use `super`*. The code you have with `super` and the code you have here are *not equivalent*

Comment: I agree completely that my code with super() was buggy and didn't work. It's been taken down.